# How to pass a dynamic array to a function in C, along with the index position?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation, pass-by-pointer

I need this functionality to pass both dynamically allocated array and idx to a function and assign values to it. Segfault is occuring when I try to allocate value 2 as mentioned in code. What is wrong in this? and how can I resolve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
void fucn(int *int_ptr, int **arr_ptr)
{

    *arr_ptr[*int_ptr] = 1;

    (*int_ptr)++;
    //*arr_ptr = *arr_ptr + 1;

    *arr_ptr[*int_ptr] = 2;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int *array = calloc(4, sizeof(int));
    int i = 0;
    fucn(&i, &array);
    printf("%d%d", array[0], array[1]);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void fucn(int *int_ptr, int **arr_ptr)` --> `void fucn(int *int_ptr, int *arr_ptr)` , `fucn(&i, &array);` --  `fucn(&i, array);` , you want a single pointer, not a pointer to pointer. And take care of that dyslexia `fucn` --> `func` :)

Comment: Thanks, it's working! Got it.

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer to pointer results in a pointer, you can not assign an integer to that pointer, otherwise you overwrite the passed pointer and it crashes trying to access again later.

Comment: @DavidRanieri then why did no segfault occur when I assign value 1, the segfault is occurring only when I try to assign value 2.

Comment: that's why I said _and it crashes trying to access again **later**_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is one of operator precedence, `*arr_ptr[i]` is *not* equivalent to `(*arr_ptr)[i]` which is what you really want here, although it would be even better to simply pass `array` to your function directly, i.e. make it take a pointer to `int` as its second argument, there is no need for the extra level of indirection.

So you should have either:

```
void func(int *int_ptr, int **arr_ptr)
{
    (*arr_ptr)[*int_ptr] = 1;

    (*int_ptr)++;

    (*arr_ptr)[*int_ptr] = 2;
}
```

Or:

```
void func(int *int_ptr, int *arr_ptr)
{
    arr_ptr[*int_ptr] = 1;

    (*int_ptr)++;

    arr_ptr[*int_ptr] = 2;
}
```

Comment: Woah, never thought, operator precedence issue was there. Thanks!

Comment: in my code, when I assign value 1, it's working properly. why is that? only when I try to assign the next value its causing segfault